# Does Swift implement tail call optimization? and in mutual recursion case?

Tags: swift, tail-call-optimization

In particular if I have the following code:

```
func sum(n: Int, acc: Int) -> Int {
  if n == 0 { return acc }
  else { return sum(n - 1, acc + n) }
}
```

Will Swift compiler optimize it to a loop? And does it so in a more interesting case below?

```
func isOdd(n: Int) -> Bool {
  if n == 0 { return false; }
  else { return isEven(n - 1) }
}

func isEven(n: Int) -> Bool {
  if n == 0 { return true }
  else { return isOdd(n - 1) }
}
```

Comment: The stack's only so big. What happens when you run an infinitely recursive function? Does it crash?

Comment: @Veedrac: It's apple. It will be converted to a loop and gets back a deterministic result.

Comment: @Veedrac - that's a given. But a functional programmer doing infinite recursion would be like an imperative programmer doing a `for` loop without a test clause, e.g. `for (int i = 0; ; i++) { println("%d", i); }`.

Comment: @Yawar I don't understand what your point is.

Comment: @Veedrac my point is a functional programmer is no more likely to do infinite recursion than an imperative programmer is to do an infinite loop.

Comment: Regarding the standalone question "Does Swift implement tail call optimization?" The short answer is "Swift doesn’t guarantee tail call optimization, so don’t rely on it". However, if you are doing recursion, you might as well attempt TCO as the compiler may well assist ;)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The best way to check is to examine the assembly language code generated by the compiler. I took the code above and compiled it with:

```
swift -O3 -S tco.swift >tco.asm
```

The relevant part of the output

```
.globl    __TF3tco3sumFTSiSi_Si
    .align    4, 0x90
__TF3tco3sumFTSiSi_Si:
    pushq    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    testq    %rdi, %rdi
    je    LBB0_4
    .align    4, 0x90
LBB0_1:
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    decq    %rax
    jo    LBB0_5
    addq    %rdi, %rsi
    jo    LBB0_5
    testq    %rax, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    jne    LBB0_1
LBB0_4:
    movq    %rsi, %rax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
LBB0_5:
    ud2

    .globl    __TF3tco5isOddFSiSb
    .align    4, 0x90
__TF3tco5isOddFSiSb:
    pushq    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    testq    %rdi, %rdi
    je    LBB1_1
    decq    %rdi
    jo    LBB1_9
    movb    $1, %al
LBB1_5:
    testq    %rdi, %rdi
    je    LBB1_2
    decq    %rdi
    jo    LBB1_9
    testq    %rdi, %rdi
    je    LBB1_1
    decq    %rdi
    jno    LBB1_5
LBB1_9:
    ud2
LBB1_1:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
LBB1_2:
    popq    %rbp
    retq

    .globl    __TF3tco6isEvenFSiSb
    .align    4, 0x90
__TF3tco6isEvenFSiSb:
    pushq    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movb    $1, %al
LBB2_1:
    testq    %rdi, %rdi
    je    LBB2_5
    decq    %rdi
    jo    LBB2_7
    testq    %rdi, %rdi
    je    LBB2_4
    decq    %rdi
    jno    LBB2_1
LBB2_7:
    ud2
LBB2_4:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
LBB2_5:
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

There are no call instructions in the generated code, only conditional jumps (`je` / `jne` / `jo` / `jno`). This clearly suggests that Swift does do tail call optimizations in *both* cases.

In addition, the `isOdd`/`isEven` functions are interesting in that the compiler not only seems to perform TCO but also inlines the other function in each case.

Comment: Oh, your word "**clearly**" makes me feel like a total dummy. But thanks for investigation- I'm sure it's pretty obvious if you know ASM.

Comment: @skywinder - sorry about that. What I meant was that there are no `call` instructions in the generated code, only conditional jumps (`je` / `jne` / `jo` / `jno`)

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: You don't really have to know ASM to understand Ferruccio's analysis. An understanding of the basics of how stacks are used is sufficient. A call instruction is a subroutine/function/method call. Those push the return address (and any parameters) onto the stack. Jump instructions don't push anything onto the stack, and so they **can't** lead to potential stack overflows.

Comment: I don't think the best way is to check the assembly code, on the contrary. If the Swift spec doesn't guarantee TCO, then whether or not it happens is implementation detail, subject to change without notice. Your application may work today, to eventually be recompiled with a new compiler version, possibly breaking.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, the swift compiler performs tail call optimisation in some cases:

```
func sum(n: Int, acc: Int) -> Int {
    if n == 0 { return acc }
    else { return sum(n - 1, acc: acc + 1) }
}
```

As a global function, this will use constant stack space on the "Fastest" optimisation level (`-O`).

If it is inside a struct it will still use constant stack space. Within a class however, the compiler does not perform tco because the method might be overridden at runtime.

Clang also supports tco for Objective-C but often ARC calls `release` after the recursive call, thus preventing this optimisation, see [this article by Jonathon Mah](http://devetc.org/code/2014/05/24/tail-recursion-objc-and-arc.html) for more details.

ARC also seems to prevent TCO in Swift:

```
func sum(n: Int, acc: Int, s: String?) -> Int {
    if n == 0 { return acc }
    else { return sum(n - 1, acc + 1, s) }
}
```

No TCO was performed in my tests.

Comment: Do you mean that the same TCO caveats Jonathon Mah describes for Obj-C apply to Swift compiler in the current (1.0) version?

Comment: @Palimondo Unfortunately, that's what it looks like to me.

Comment: I wouldn't say that ARC prevents TCO, but rather that since ARC has to add a release call before returning from a function, the recursive call is no longer in the tail position.

Comment: @Sebastian, so from what I understand, TCO works for cases where no references are involved i.e. calling functions and methods on structs is fine but methods on classes get released and therefore are not optimized? Or are functions copied by reference and therefore subject to ARC?