# Iterating based on a variable number of inner loops

Tags: swift, swift2

In the below code I am trying to go through all possible combination of alphabets for number of characters which are runtime variable.

The purpose of this code is to build a kind of password cracker, which basically brute-force guess the string. I want to use loop, because I will be able to break the loop as soon as the correct combination is hit thus saving on time and resources which otherwise will be required if I try to build an array of all possible combinations in first step.

I have a static code which works for a string 5 characters long but in reality my string could be any length. How can I make my code work with any length of string?

```
let len = textField.text?.characters.count //Length of string
let charRange = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" //Allowed characterset

for char1 in charRange.characters {
    for char2 in charRange.characters {
        for char3 in charRange.characters {
            for char4 in charRange.characters {
                for char5 in charRange.characters {
                     // Do whatever with all possible combinations
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I have to utilize `for totalChars in 1...len {` somehow but can't figure out how the for loops are going to be created dynamically?

Comment: This is more algorithmic question than a Swift problem. A common approach is to use *recursion*.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, do you just want a way of finding all possible combinations of characters in a string?

Comment: @Oliver: I want to try all possible combinations of permissible alphabets in a certain string length against the question string (kind of a password cracker).

Comment: For 8 characters in "a" ... "z" that would be 26^8 = 208827064576 combinations ... :) If you process 10,000 combinations per second then you'll need about 240 days.

Comment: @Martin: Yes I understand that and also understand the resources required to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by *Martin R*, you can use recursion

### This is the function

```
func visit(alphabet:[Character], combination:[Character], inout combinations:[String], length: Int) {
    guard length > 0 else {
        combinations.append(String(combination))
        return
    }

    alphabet.forEach {
        visit(alphabet, combination: combination + [$0], combinations: &combinations, length: length - 1)
    }
}
```

### The helper function

```
func combinations(alphabet: String, length: Int) -> [String] {
    var combinations = [String]()
    visit([Character](alphabet.characters), combination: [Character](), combinations: &combinations, length: length)
    return combinations
}
```

### Test

Now if you want every combination of 3 chars, and you want `"ab"` as alphabet then

```
combinations("ab", length: 3) // ["aaa", "aab", "aba", "abb", "baa", "bab", "bba", "bbb"]
```

### Duplicates

Please note that if you insert duplicates into your alphabet, you'll get duplicate elements into the result.

### Time complexity

The `visit` function is invoked as many times as the nodes into a perfect `k-ary` tree with height `h` where:

- `k`: the number of elements into the `alphabet` param
- `h`: the `length` param

Such a tree has

[image]

nodes. And this is the exact number of times the function will be invoked.

### Space complexity

<s>*Theoretically*</s> The max number of stack frames allocated at the same time to execute visit is `length`.

<s>However since the Swift compiler does implement the [Tail Call Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023580/does-swift-implement-tail-call-optimization-and-in-mutual-recursion-case) the number of allocated stack frames is only 1.</s>

Finally we must consider that `combinations` will be as big as the number of results: `alphabet^length`

So the time complexity is the max of `length` and `elements into the result`.

And it is `O(length + alphabet^length)`

---

### Update

It turns out you want a brute force password breaker so.

```
func find(alphabet:[Character], combination:[Character] = [Character](), length: Int, check: (keyword:String) -> Bool) -> String? {
    guard length > 0 else {
        let keyword = String(combination)
        return check(keyword: keyword) ? keyword : nil
    }

    for char in alphabet {
        if let keyword = find(alphabet, combination: combination + [char], length: length - 1, check: check) {
            return keyword
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

The last param `check` is a closure to verify if the current word is the correct password. You will put your logic here and the `find` will stop as soon as the password is found.

Example

```
find([Character]("tabcdefghil".characters), length: 3) { (keyword) -> Bool in
    return keyword == "cat" // write your code to verify the password here
}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think there is a tail call in the `visit()` method, as the last statement does the recursive call from within a loop.

Comment: Hi @MartinR, I believed that putting the only recursive call at the end of the function was enough. Am I wrong?

Comment: But the recursive call isn't the last statement in the function, it is inside a loop. And how should that work if the function calls itself *n times*?

Comment: @MartinR: I see your point and I'm going to update my answer. Thank you. Every time you answer or comment a post it is an opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: This would indeed give me an array of all possible combinations but the reason I asked for a way to go through all combinations through loop is that I am able to terminate the loop as soon as I find the combination I am looking for and thus save on time/resources required (which can exponentially increase as the length of string and range of characters will increase.

Comment: @Kashif: well you should have said that in your question... :)

Comment: @Kashif: So, given an `alphabet`, a `length` and a `keyword` you want to know if it is possible to build that `keyword` using the `alphabet`? This is a very different problem.

Comment: It is kind of a password cracker, so I am trying to brute force guess the string.

Comment: @Kashif: I added a new section to my answer. Please check if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: form the string using an array of indices into your alphabet; each time increment the indices.

```
[0, 0, 0] -> [1, 0, 0] -> [2, 0, 0] ->
[0, 1, 0] -> [1, 1, 0] -> [2, 1, 0] ->
[0, 2, 0] -> [1, 2, 0] -> [2, 2, 0] ->
[0, 0, 1] ... [2, 2, 2]
```

Here's an example using a length of 3 and an alphabet of `abcd`

```
let len = 3
let alphabet = "abcd".characters.map({ String($0) })
var allStrings = [String]()
let maxIndex = alphabet.endIndex
var indicies = Array(count: len, repeatedValue: 0)

outerLoop: while (true) {
    // Generate string from indicies
    var string = ""
    for i in indicies {
        let letter = alphabet[i]
        string += letter
    }
    allStrings.append(string)
    print("Adding \(string)")

    // Increment the index
    indicies[0] += 1

    var idx = 0
    // If idx overflows then (idx) = 0 and (idx + 1) += 1 and try next
    while (indicies[idx] == maxIndex) {
        // Reset current
        indicies[idx] = 0
        // Increment next (as long as we haven't hit the end done)
        idx += 1
        if (idx >= alphabet.endIndex - 1) {
            print("Breaking outer loop")
            break outerLoop
        }
        indicies[idx] += 1
    }
}

print("All Strings: \(allStrings)")
```

Comment: This would indeed give me an array of all possible combinations but the reason I asked for a way to go through all combinations through loop is that I am able to terminate the loop as soon as I find the combination I am looking for and thus save on time/resources required (which can exponentially increase as the length of string and range of characters will increase.

Comment: In that case you could just compare the strings instead of `allStrings.append(string)`

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative to recursion; loop radix representation of incremental (repeated) traversing of your alphabet

An alternative to recursion is to loop over an numeral representation of your alphabet, using a radix representative for the different number of letters. A limitation with this method is that the `String(_:,radix:)` initializer allows at most base36 numbers (radix 36), i.e., you can at most perform your "password cracking" with a set of characters with a unique count <=36.

---

*Help function*

```
// help function to use to pad incremental alphabeth cycling to e.g. "aa..."
let padToTemplate: (str: String, withTemplate: String) -> String = {
    return $0.characters.count < $1.characters.count
        ? String($1.characters.suffixFrom($0.characters.endIndex)) + $0
        : $0
}
```

*Main radix brute-force password checking method*

```
// attempt brute-force attempts to crack isCorrectPassword closure
// for a given alphabet, suspected word length and for a maximum number of 
// attempts, optionally with a set starting point
func bruteForce(isCorrectPassword: (String) -> Bool, forAlphabet alphabet: [Character], forWordLength wordLength: Int, forNumberOfAttempts numAttempts: Int, startingFrom start: Int = 0) -> (Int, String?) {
    
    // remove duplicate characters (but preserve order)
    var exists: [Character:Bool] = [:]
    let uniqueAlphabet = Array(alphabet.filter { return exists.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil })
    
    // limitation: allows at most base36 radix
    guard case let radix = uniqueAlphabet.count
        where radix < 37 else {
        return (-1, nil)
    }
    
    // begin brute-force attempts
    for i in start..<start+numAttempts {
        let baseStr = String(i, radix: radix).characters
            .flatMap { Int(String($0), radix: radix) }
            .map { String(uniqueAlphabet[$0]) }
            .joinWithSeparator("")
        
        // construct attempt of correct length
        let attempt = padToTemplate(str: baseStr,
            withTemplate: String(count: wordLength, repeatedValue: alphabet.first!))
        
        // log
        //print(i, attempt)
        
        // test attempt
        if isCorrectPassword(attempt) { return (i, attempt) }
    }
    return (start+numAttempts, nil) // next to test
}
```

---

#### Example usage

Example usage #1

```
// unknown content closure
let someHashBashing : (String) -> Bool = {
    return $0 == "ask"
}

// setup alphabet
let alphabet = [Character]("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters)

// any success for 500 attempts?
if case (let i, .Some(let password)) =
    bruteForce(someHashBashing, forAlphabet: alphabet,
               forWordLength: 3, forNumberOfAttempts: 500) {
    print("Password cracked: \(password) (attempt \(i))")
} /* Password cracked: ask (attempt 478) */
```

Example usage #2 (picking up one failed "batch" with another)

```
// unknown content closure
let someHashBashing : (String) -> Bool = {
    return $0 == "axk"
}

// setup alphabet
let alphabet = [Character]("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters)

// any success for 500 attempts?
let firstAttempt = bruteForce(someHashBashing, forAlphabet: alphabet,
                              forWordLength: 3, forNumberOfAttempts: 500)
if let password = firstAttempt.1 {
    print("Password cracked: \(password) (attempt \(firstAttempt.0))")
}
// if not, try another 500?
else {
    if case (let i, .Some(let password)) =
        bruteForce(someHashBashing, forAlphabet: alphabet,
                   forWordLength: 3, forNumberOfAttempts: 500,
                   startingFrom: firstAttempt.0) {
        print("Password cracked: \(password) (attempt \(i))")
    } /* Password cracked: axk (attempt 608) */
}
```