# Does Swift have a function similar to numpy.diff that calculates the difference between adjacent elements of an array

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert some Python code to Swift and wondering if there is an existing function to calculate the difference between successive elements in a Swift array.  For example:

```
diff([1,3,5,6,10]) would return [2,2,1,4]
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: You can pretty easily write one though.

Answer (score 8):

No, but it could be very easily implemented:

```
let a = [1, 3, 5, 6, 10]
zip(a.dropFirst(), a).map(-) // => [2, 2, 1, 4]
```

It's simple enough that it's probably not worth wrapping into a function, but if you insist:

```
extension Collection where Element: Numeric {
    func diff() -> [Element] {
        return zip(self.dropFirst(), self).map(-)
    }
}

[1, 3, 5, 6, 10].diff() // => [2, 2, 1, 4]
```

If you need the result to be lazily evaluated, you can do this:

```
extension Collection where Element: Numeric {
    func diff() -> AnyCollection<Element> {
        return AnyCollection(zip(self.dropFirst(), self).lazy.map(-))
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this uses twice memory as needed and it also iterates through it twice

Comment: @LeoDabus Not anymore :)

Comment: @LeoDabus can you explain more , are `Zip` for very large array of Int will be work badly

Comment: @LeoDabus Actually, `zip` is lazy, it merely wraps two sequences and defines an iterator over them that calls their iterators. It's just a single loop through the elements, done by `map`. If you use `.lazy`, you can even prevent that loop, too!

Comment: @LeoDabus It doesn't create an intermediate array of tuples. Try `dump(zip([1, 2], [3, 4]))`.

Comment: @Alexander can you explain what is  `lazily evaluated` or send me any link that explain more about lazy sequence

Answer (score 4):

You can use reduce(into:) combined with dropfirst to achieve what you want:

```
extension Collection where Element: SignedNumeric {
    func diff() -> [Element] {
        guard var last = first else { return [] }
        return dropFirst().reduce(into: []) {
            $0.append($1 - last)
            last = $1
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to use map and defer:

```
extension Collection where Element: SignedNumeric {
    func diff() -> [Element] {
        guard var last = first else { return [] }
        return dropFirst().map { element in
            defer { last = element }
            return element - last
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let arr = [1,3,5,6,10]
print(arr.diff())  // "[2, 2, 1, 4]\n"
```

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in function for this, but you can easily implement it recursively. Thanks for the `HeadTail` extension for @Alexander.

```
extension Array {
    func headTail<ReturnType>(_ closure: (Element?, [Element]) -> ReturnType) -> ReturnType {
        return closure(self.first, Array(self.dropFirst()))
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Int {
    func diff() -> [Int] {
        return self.headTail { head, tail in
            guard let head = head, let next = tail.first else { return [] } //base case, empty list
            return [next - head] + tail.diff()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I very strongly recommend against implementing this recursively. Not only is it way slower, the small stack size and lack of tail recursion is crippling.

Comment: @Alexander are you sure that's the case? According to [Does Swift implement tail call optimization? and in mutual recursion case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023580/does-swift-implement-tail-call-optimization-and-in-mutual-recursion-case), the compiler does implement tail recursion.

Comment: Interesting. I stand corrected. In any case, I would avoid it for the complexity, when such a simpler solution exists

Comment: @Alexander I do agree, your solution is way simpler and probably even more efficient. I'll just keep my answer here if OP/anyone else is interested in seeing different solutions, including a recursive one.

Comment: @Alexander thanks, that does improve readability, updated my answer.

Comment: There is no need to pass any arguments to your method `extension Array where Element == Int {
    func diff() -> [Int] {
        return headTail { head, tail in
            guard let head = head, let next = tail.first else { return [] } //base case, empty list
            return [next - head] + tail.diff()
        }
    }
}`

Comment: `extension Array {
    func headTail<T>(_ closure: (Element?, [Element]) -> T) -> T {
        return closure(first, Array(dropFirst()))
    }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, I forgot to update the method when I moved it to an extension.

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right again, now it should be fine. I'm completely aware of the naming convention, but I copied the `HeadTail` method from Alexander, so didn't want to modify it, but updated the method name.

Comment: @DávidPásztor btw no need to initialize a new Array for every tail. you can just change the return type to ArraySlice. `extension Array {
    func headTail<T>(_ closure: (Element?, ArraySlice<Element>) -> T) -> T {
        return closure(first, dropFirst())
    }
}`

Comment: another option is to extend Collection instead of Array. `extension Collection {
    func headTail<T>(_ closure: (Element?, SubSequence) -> T) -> T {
        return closure(first, dropFirst(1))
    }
}
extension Collection where Element == Int {
    func diff() -> [Element] {
        return headTail {
            guard let head = $0, let next = $1.first else { return [] }
            return [next - head] + $1.diff()
        }
    }
}`